# What is the piece value heuristic in atomic chess?

Tags: point-value, atomic-chess

In regular chess a queen is worth 9, rook 5, knight 3, etc. What is the equivalent heuristic in atomic chess?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is, as expected, "it depends". To answer directly first, 2016 Atomic World Championship (AWC) winner, tipau, [put the values as](https://lichess.org/forum/team-atomic-chess-theoreticians/value-of-pieces-in-atomic-chess):

> Pawn - 1
> Knight - 1.5
> Bishop - 1.5
> Rook - 3
> Queen - 6

As a [somewhat strong player myself](https://lichess.org/@/Illion) (two top-8 finishes in the AWC) who has extensively analysed atomic chess endgames, I would tend to agree.

The king has no value, but outside of stopping passed pawns in endgames and a few other special zugzwang compositions, it is almost useless.

---

Now to go deeper into the topic, do note that the **piece values change during the game**. General experience would give the following points to support the piece values:

- In an endgame, a minor piece is only slightly more than a pawn; if one side has *N* pawns + 1 minor piece while the other side has *N+1* pawns, the side with the minor piece has a slight advantage (which may not be enough to win, depending on the position).
- In the middlegame, a minor piece is worth more than a pawn, but usually less than two pawns.
- A rook is generally worth more than a minor piece, especially when there are more open files for invasion. A minor piece + pawn can compensate for a rook in the endgame though, generally forcing the side with the rook to take a draw by perpetual check.
- Knights are generally better than bishops in the very early opening and endgame, but not in the middlegame.
- The bishop pair is much stronger than the knight pair or a knight + bishop.
- The queen's value is hard to pin down. Depending on the position, she can be worth less than B+N, or more than R+B+N+P, as seen in several common opening lines. It largely depends on the solidity of both sides' positions.
- Factors like piece activity, pawn structure, passed pawns and other non-material considerations also matter in any given position.

I would therefore recommend using the following rules of thumb instead of exact point values:

- B ~ N (depends)
- N/B slightly > P
- B+B > 2 minors
- R > N/B
- R ~ N/B + P
- R > P+P
- R < B+N
- Q somewhere between B+N and R+B+N+P